# Freeing space Cloudera-QuickStart VM- Cent OS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, centos, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I ran a MR job that filled up a bit of space while testing.   It Almost 20 GB space has been taken by running the Job. I  have deleted a number of hive tables and hdfs files.  But, I still run into errors such as failing the parcel directory thresholds.

Is there any Cloudera Manager command that will clean unused space across all nodes?   Or is there some other method I should be using to make free space?

```
Container [pid=10156,containerID=container_1511328141399_0037_01_000004] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.0 GB of 1 GB physical memory used; 23.1 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1511328141399_0037_01_000004 :
```

Comment: The error message displayed has nothing to do with disk space. It's about RAM - that job needs bigger containers, change your MapRed config...

Comment: ok, But in my C drive 20 GB space got reduced.  How to restore that?

Comment: Again, RAM is the error, not disk

Comment: How to get back my 20GB back in my laptop..

Answer (score 0):

First, your error is about memory, not disk space. You needed 8GB of RAM to have the Cloudera Express desktop app to start, unless you forced it to start otherwise

Deleting HDFS files still keeps them around in a Trash location in a user's home folder.

Hue has an option to empty the trash, but the command line option is

```
hdfs dfs -expunge
```

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#expunge

Note that you could also manipulate the VirtualBox hard drive to be larger, which is outside the scope of the quickstart VM. It's not clear if you're using the Docker version, though